# MAX5035 DC-DC Converter Problem

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I am using MAX5035 for a DC-DC(5V output, 9-72V input) converter.

The circuit works fine for 7.6-20V input. The output begins to rise for input above 20V.

Please suggest reasons for such a response.

Comment: link to datasheet is https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX5035.pdf

Comment: I have used the circuit given in figure 1 on page 10. R1 = 1M, R2 = 270k, input cap = 100uF, LX-BST cap = 0.1uF, VD-GND cap = 0.1uF, Cout = 47uF, L = 100uH, R3 = 4.7k, R4 = 1.5k

Comment: rise by mV (possibly heating affecting the reference, and relatviely innocuous) or rise by volts (obviously a problem)? Give table of input/output voltages, preferrably at a few different stated loads.

Comment: I am running the circuit at no load

Comment: How you are testing? How you increase the input voltage. 100uH is less for higher input voltages. select bigger Inductor >~150uH.

Comment: load is disconnected. Then I start rising the input voltage gradually from a power supply and when the input reaches 20V the output starts to increase. I have already checked with 200uH and 500uH and on both occasions the input voltage range decreased.

Comment: "Load is disconnected" That's a major issue. The controller can't go to indefinitely short on time and you are in deep discontinuous mode.

Comment: connected a 56ohm resistor as load but got 0.9V at output. Increasing the load to 1k gives 5V at output but again above 20V input the output starts to increase

Answer (score 1):

> I am running the circuit at no load – mka 4 hours ago

Read the data sheet: -

[image]

Note also that the maximum output voltage allowed according to the data sheet is **NOT** 20 volts.

Comment: I changed the schottkey diode and resoldered the circuit and it is working now. But the problem is the circuit output begins to fluctuate as the load is increased beyond 500mA. Why is that so?

Comment: At what voltage does the output fluctuate and by how much and how often and does it get worse as you increase the load? Are you sure it isn't just natural ripple voltage at the switching frequency?